# PyQt5 how to start multiprocess but in not main thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5, qthread

I am writing a program that reads data from an excel file to some system via API.
The function that fetches data from excel and sends it via API is in a separate thread to keep the GUI alive.
Loading via API is a long process. Most of the time is sending and waiting for API data.
I wanted to send each excel line in a separate process. How to do it?

```
def api_import(k, sheet,number_columns, items_number, ok, total, total_success):
   item = sheet[get_column_letter(3)+str(k)].value
   templ_id = sheet[get_column_letter(number_columns)+str(k)].value
   item_id = get_item_id(item)['item_id']
   query = {"template_id": str(templ_id)}
   resp = templ_attach(item_id, query)
   if resp==200:
      ok += 1
   total += 1
   item_create_param = 0
   item_update_param = 0
   item_error = 0

   for l in range(number_columns):
       if l <4:
           pass
       else:
           param_name = sheet[get_column_letter(l)+str(1).upper().replace(" ", "")].value
           param_description = sheet[get_column_letter(l)+str(2)].value
           param_value = sheet[get_column_letter(l)+str(k)].value
           param_type = sheet[get_column_letter(l)+str(3)].value
           if "[T]" in param_type:
               param_type = 4
               query = {"name": str(param_name), "type": param_type, "description": str(param_description), "text_value": str(param_value)}
           elif "[D]" in param_type:
               param_type = 0
               query = {"name": str(param_name), "type": param_type, "description": str(param_description), "numeric_value": param_value}
           else:
               param_type = 1
               query = {"name": str(param_name), "type": param_type, "description": str(param_description), "logical_value": param_value}
        
           resp = input_param(item_id, query)
           if resp==201:
               item_create_param += 1
           elif resp==202:
               item_update_param += 1
           else:
            item_error += 1

            
   if item_error == 0:
       total_success += 1
   return {'total':total, 'total_success':total_success, 'ok':ok}

class MainWindow(QDialog):
   def __init__(self):
       super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
       loadUi("gui.ui",self)
       self.browse.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)
       self.load.clicked.connect(self.send)

   def browsefiles(self):
       fname=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'C:\Program files', 'Excel Spreadsheet files (*.xlsx, *.xls)')
       self.filename.setText(fname[0])


   def send(self):
       self.worker = WorkerThread()
       self.worker.start()
       #self.worker.worker_complete.connect(self.evt_worker_finished)
       self.worker.update_progress.connect(self.evt_update_progress)

   #def evt_worker_finished(self, emp):
       #self.QMessageBox.information(self, "Done!", "Wczytywanie zakonczone!\n\n{} {}".format(emp["fn"], emp["ln"]))

   def evt_update_progress(self, val):
       self.progressBar.setValue(val)

class WorkerThread(QThread):
   update_progress = pyqtSignal(int)
   worker_complete = pyqtSignal(dict)
   def run(self):        
       start_time = time.time()

       file_path = "import.xlsx"
       print(file_path)
       wb = load_workbook(file_path)
       sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
   
       for sheet in wb:
           print(sheet)
           number_rows = sheet.max_row
           print(number_rows)
           number_columns = sheet.max_column
           items_number = number_rows-3
           ok = 0
           total = 0
           progress = 0
           total_success = 0
           for k in range(number_rows+1):
               if k>3:
                   report = api_import(k, sheet,number_columns, items_number, ok, total, total_success)
                   total = report['total']
                   ok = report['ok']
                   total_success = report['total_success']
                   progress = round(total/items_number*100)
                   print("{}%".format(progress))
                   self.update_progress.emit(progress)

                
       self.worker_complete.emit({"emp_id":1234, "fn":"XXX", "ln":"YYYY"})

       end_time = time.time() - start_time
       item_time = end_time/total
```

Comment: Have you tried `QProcess`? Here is a tutorial: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qprocess-external-programs/

Comment: Are you asking if you can use multiprocessing to work on the *same file*, while processing different rows for each process? If that's the case, you cannot.